# Why isn't Postman's Visualize rendering HTML styling

Tags: postman, handlebars.js

Given the following JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "Foo",
        "Value": "This does not have HTML styling."
    },
    {
        "Key": "Bar",
        "Value": "<i>This</i> has <b>some</b> HTML styling."
    }
]
```

And using the following to visualize the response:

```
var template = `
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>

        {{#each response}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{Key}}</td>
                <td>{{Value}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
`;

pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    response: pm.response.json()
});
```

Why is the  and  styling not being rendered?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to render the HTML styling, a "triple-stash" is needed. See the docs for [handlebarsjs](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping) which Postman seems to use for the Visualize tab.

Replace

`<td>{{Value}}</td>`

with

`<td>{{{Value}}}</td>`

[image]